# Accessing files remotely

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I want to access some files on my friends PC remotely

He has an ADSL and a static IP (and he's behind a router).
I have an ADSL and changing IP (and I'm behind a router).

He's using [Http File Server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) on port 80

and we tried the port 55554 also and it did not work either.

Isn't this is the right way to get to his PC? to put http:// His_Ip:80/downloads

P.S: I've put a space in the link because I can't post more than 1 link due to my reputation.

Comment: he should first try to connect to it from not his own computer 127.0.0.1 and next, from another computer on his LAN. Those tests will rule out the router. And it'd be h tee tee pee colon slash slash hisip:80/ where 80 is whatever port , and it needn't be /downloads just try the root http ://ip:port/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things can go wrong here:

1. Your friend's ISP blocks the port 80 since (web) servers are not allowed for private use
2. The router does not forward the incoming port 80 (or 55556) to the local machine. You should use VNAT for this, or dynamic port forwarding (the name depends on the router), but it allows you to tell the router to forward any port 80 request to the local IP address of your friend's computer (i.e. 192.168.1.5). Look for this setting in the router, it is **mostly** the main source of problem here.
3. The HTTP Server is not working locally. Try accessing `http://localhost:80` from your friend's computer and see if that works.

If not, get another solution to share files, like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or a more complex solution like [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Hamachi: https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/hamachi2/

It is free for personal use, and pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port.  Many ISPs block outgoing port 80 so that people don't use their service to run a web host.